# Appear object data only one time

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently, whenever I run the following code, "supplier" data show multiple times in the result because I have it in my table in multiple rows, but I would like it to appear only one time.

```
orders = Order.objects.all()
    supplier = request.GET.get('supplier')
    product = request.GET.get('product')
    if supplier:
        orders = orders.filter(supplier_id=supplier)
    if product:
        orders = orders.filter(product_id=product)

    for tr in orders:
        table_row = [str(tr.supplier)]
        table_data.append(table_row)
```

Is there any way to appear only one time inside the loop or without the loop?

Comment: Have you tried putting the suppliers into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)?

Comment: I tried this way. but this printing multiple time 
```for tr in orders:
        table_row = set([tr.supplier])
        table_data.append(table_row)
```